# How to format time and date from db:datetime record in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `var` in my view returning date and time from a `datetime` database record as UTC format. The output looks like this: `2014-01-21 03:13:59 UTC`

How do I format this? `Date.parse(var)` will give `#=> Tue, 21 Jan 2014` in IRB but a type error in RAILS 4 of: *"no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String"*

I ultimately would like to display just the date; formatted as: `%m/%d/%Y` My only option can't be to: `to_s` and `regex` this right? **Someone please show me the RAILS way.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Date#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
Date.parse('2014-01-21 03:13:59 UTC').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# => "01/21/2014"
```

If `var` is [`TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) object, just call [`TimeWithZone#strftime` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-strftime):

```
var.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I tried that. This is making my head spin. I get back: "no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String"

Comment: And what I call `to_s` on the var, I get back: Invalid Date

Comment: On your second suggestion, I get back: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It is a `datetime` field. I just tried: `var.to_s.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` and I get: undefined method `strftime' for "2014-01-21 03:13:59 UTC":String

Comment: Ok your last suggestions yields: undefined method strtime' for Tue, 21 Jan 2014 03:13:59 UTC +00:00:Time (I removed `to_s`)

Comment: Son of a gun! That last suggestion worked. (After the spelling correction) Thank you @falsetru!

Comment: I like your style :) Hey I realize now my mistake. It wasn't my code as I tried `strftime` several times. It was putting in the conditional for records that returned `nil` instead of a UTC time to convert. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that Rails' way is to name that format in an initializer and to use the named date format with the [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) (or its `to_s` alias):

```
# in config/initializers/date_time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(date_us: '%m/%d/%Y')
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(date_us: '%m/%d/%Y')
```

And then use this named format in your view like this:

```
<%= @object.date.to_s(format: :date_us) %>
```

This allows you to reuse this named format in your application without writing the complex `strftime` string multiple times. You can add several different formats and have one place in your app to change all existing formats.

If you are going to localize your application into different languages then you might want to consider storing those formats in your locale YAML files. This allows you to use different formats depending on the user's location. Read more about it in the official [Rails Guide about I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).