# DateTime showing as nil in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm working in Rails 4 and trying to format a datetime being pulled from the SQLite DB.  I'm working in the model but the object class is behaving very strangely.

If I type:
`Duration <%= micropost.duration %>`

then it prints the full datetime.  I only want the time.

If I type:
`Duration <%= micropost.duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>`

then I get the error: 
`undefined method`strftime' for nil:NilClass`

So I try typing:
`Duration <%= micropost.duration.class %>`

and it returns the type: `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

It looks like it sometimes recognizes the type and sometimes not.  To compound the issue, in the IRB the `strftime("%H:%M:%S")` method works.

There was a similar issue raised in [How to format time and date from db:datetime record in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249048/how-to-format-time-and-date-from-dbdatetime-record-in-rails-4) but that solution did not work. Am I even looking in the right place?

Comment: Did your micropost is inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying it inside loop and any of micropost duration is nil. Try this

```
Duration <%= micropost.duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S") if micropost.duration.present? %>
```

Comment: Yup.  That was the issue.  Somehow my seed data is not populating Times right.  Thanks!